# Why does my JavaScript calculator not allow me to add/subtract numbers?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

The problem of my code is that it **doesnt allow me to add or multiply the numbers together** but it does allow me to click them. I would like to know why does it not allow me to add/multiply/subtract the numbers together? It also **doesnt allow me to type them in to the top of the calculator**.

```js
var buttons = [];
var font;
var btn0;
var input;
var result;

function setup() {
  noCanvas();

  font = loadFont('AvenirNextLTPro-Demi.otf', 40);
  result = createP('&nbsp;');
  input = createInput('');
  buttons.push(result);
  buttons.push(input);
  createElement('br');
  buttons.push(createButton('&radic;'));
  buttons.push(createButton('('));
  buttons.push(createButton(')'));
  buttons.push(createButton('&larr;'));
  createElement('br');
  buttons.push(createButton('7'));
  buttons.push(createButton('8'));
  buttons.push(createButton('9'));
  buttons.push(createButton('&divide;'));
  createElement('br');
  buttons.push(createButton('4'));
  buttons.push(createButton('5'));
  buttons.push(createButton('6'));
  buttons.push(createButton('&times;'));
  createElement('br');
  buttons.push(createButton('1'));
  buttons.push(createButton('2'));
  buttons.push(createButton('3'));
  buttons.push(createButton('&minus;'));
  createElement('br');
  btn0 = createButton('0');
  buttons.push(btn0);
  buttons.push(createButton('.'));
  buttons.push(createButton('&plus;'));
  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].style('padding', '10px 40px')
              .style('width', '120px')
              .style('box-sizing', 'border-box')
              .style('font-size', '2.5em')
              .style('background-color', 'rgb(0, 28, 60)')
              .style('color', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)')
              .style('border-style', 'solid')
              .style('border-color', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)')
              .style('cursor', 'pointer')
              .style('outline', 'none')
              .style('margin', '0')
              .style('font-family', font)
              .mousePressed(add);
  }
  btn0.style('width', '240px');
  input.style('font-size', '1.9em')
       .style('cursor', 'default')
       .style('width', '480px')
       .style('padding-left', '10px')
       .style('padding-right', '10px');
  result.style('width', '481px')
        .style('background-color', 'rgb(0, 120, 255)')
        .style('text-align', 'center')
        .style('font-size', '5em');
}

function add() {
  input.html(input.html() + this.html());
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

I would like the calculator to be able to be type the numbers in together and be added/multiplied. Thank you.

Comment: Hey you don't call any function....

Comment: FYI @marcdahan the setup() function is called automatically by p5js. And the `add` function is set as the mousePressed handler for all the buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue, as far as having the numbers "typed" into the input, is that input elements (created by `createInput` in p5js), do not display their HTML content, which is what is set by the `.html()` function. You want to use the `.value()` function instead: `input.value(input.value() + this.html())`.

As for performing calculations such as addition and multiplication, I don't see any code for that, so you'll need to add code for that somewhere, either as different mousePressed handlers for the different buttons, or as a `switch` statement in your existing `add` event handler function.

```js
var buttons = [];
var font;
var btn0;
var input;
var result;

function setup() { 
  noCanvas();
  
  font = loadFont('AvenirNextLTPro-Demi.otf', 40);
  result = createP('&nbsp;');
  input = createInput('');
  buttons.push(result);
  buttons.push(input);
  createElement('br');
  buttons.push(createButton('&radic;'));
  buttons.push(createButton('('));
  buttons.push(createButton(')'));
  buttons.push(createButton('&larr;'));
  createElement('br');
  buttons.push(createButton('7'));
  buttons.push(createButton('8'));
  buttons.push(createButton('9'));
  buttons.push(createButton('&divide;'));
  createElement('br');
  buttons.push(createButton('4'));
  buttons.push(createButton('5'));
  buttons.push(createButton('6'));
  buttons.push(createButton('&times;'));
  createElement('br');
  buttons.push(createButton('1'));
  buttons.push(createButton('2'));
  buttons.push(createButton('3'));
  buttons.push(createButton('&minus;'));
  createElement('br');
  btn0 = createButton('0');
  buttons.push(btn0);
  buttons.push(createButton('.'));
  buttons.push(createButton('&plus;'));
  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].style('padding', '10px 20px')
              .style('width', '80px')
              .style('box-sizing', 'border-box')
              .style('font-size', '2.5em')
              .style('background-color', 'rgb(0, 28, 60)')
              .style('color', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)')
              .style('border-style', 'solid')
              .style('border-color', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)')
              .style('cursor', 'pointer')
              .style('outline', 'none')
              .style('margin', '0')
              .style('font-family', font)
              .mouseReleased(add);
  }
  btn0.style('width', '240px');
  input.style('font-size', '1.9em')
       .style('cursor', 'default')
       .style('width', '480px')
       .style('padding-left', '10px')
       .style('padding-right', '10px');
  result.style('width', '481px')
        .style('background-color', 'rgb(0, 120, 255)')
        .style('text-align', 'center')
        .style('font-size', '5em');
} 

function add() {
  input.value(input.value() + this.html());
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```